# Disprove the existence of $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x+y+z}{x^2y^2z^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that the following limit does not exist in $\mathbb{R^3}$, but I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem. 
The limit is as follows: \begin{equation} 
\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x+y+z}{x^2y^2z^2}
\end{equation}

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Hint**: The function isn't defined on any axis and thus you can not approach the origin  **any** way you want...

Comment: Hint: the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits

Comment: suppose $x = y = z$  and then let as x approaches 0, and the limit does not exist.

Comment: We can maybe prove something about $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x {x^2}$$ and then proceed by adding a variable at a time.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand your comment. Why does it matter that you cannot approach the origin along the axis?

Comment: @Ovi If the limit exists  it then must be that we get the same value over **any** path we choose to approach the wanted point (in this case) in $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio Doesn't that statement apply only for the domain of the function? For example, take the function $f(x, y) = x+y$ with domain $\{(x, y):y=x\}$. If we take $\displaystyle \lim_{(x, y) \to (1, 1)} f(x, y)$ wouldn't we still get $2$, even though we can only approach $(1, 1)$ along the line $y=x$?

Comment: @Ovi I think it could depend on the chose definition, though as far as I remember a *necessary* condition for the limit to exist is that the function is defined in some *open (punctured, if you want) neighborhood* of the point towards which the variable tends...just as with one variable. For example, $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\,\sqrt x\;$ isn't even well defined as $\;\sqrt x\;$ isn't defined in an open punctured neigh. of zero. At most we could talk of the one sided limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0+}\,\sqrt x\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah yes. It's weird for me, from one class I remember the way you said it. But from another class (Complex Analysis) I remember that we had the following theorem: "Suppose $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ and $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) = w_0.$ Suppose $\widetilde{G} \subseteq G$ and $z_0$ is an accumulation point of $\widetilde{G}$. If $\widetilde{f}$ is a restriction of $f$ to $\widetilde{G}$ then $\lim_{z \to z_0} \widetilde{f}(z)$ exists and has the value $w_0$." The book then used the theorem  to show that various limits don't exist by approaching them on different lines. I took this to mean

Comment: @DonAntonio that they are making new functions $\widetilde{f}$ with domains which were just lines, and calculating the limits.

Comment: @Ovi Yes, but *also in complex analysis* we require the function is defined in an open neighborhood of the point.

Comment: @DonAntonio I would say we could ask whether the limit of $f(x,y,z)$ exists for $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ as soon as the domain of $f$ has $(0,0,0)$ as a closure point (contact point). For example, if $f$ is defined as $f(x,y,z)=42$ for $x>0,y>0,z>0$, and $f$ is undefined elsewhere, I would still say that the limit exists. For every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a sufficiently small neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$ such that for all $(x,y,z)$ in the _intersection_ of that neighborhood with the domain of $f$, we have that the value of $f(x,y,z)$ is no further than $\epsilon$ away from $42$.

Comment: (continued) Of course it is simply a matter of what definition you use. "My" convention is supported by [Wikipedia: Limit of a function § Functions on metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_metric_spaces) and also § Functions on topological spaces, below that.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That one is a definition I would be willing to accept, yet there seems to be confusion in this matter. For example, here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Limits.aspx , which is a rather well known site. Anyway, I agree this is a matter of agreement on definitions, and thus it is just a matter of researching which approach leads to the better understanding and better applications.

Comment: @DonAntonio To avoid confusion, one can write (from the Wikipedia link) $$L = \underset{x\in S}{\lim_{x\to p}} f(x)$$ to emphasize that the limit is for $x$ tending to $p$, but only within the subset $S$ on which $f$ (or some restriction of $f$) is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it will help to think of parametric curves approaching $(0,0,0)$. If the limit exists, then it will be the same along every parametric curve approaching $(0,0,0)$.

$x=y=z=t$

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x+y+z}{x^2y^2z^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{3}{t^5}$$

yet

$$ \lim_{t\to0^+}\dfrac{3}{t^5}=\infty$$

while

$$ \lim_{t\to0^-}\dfrac{3}{t^5}=-\infty$$

Or, let $x=2t,\,y=-t,\,z=-t$. In this case

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x+y+z}{x^2y^2z^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{0}{t^5}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$x=y=z=\frac {1}{3n },$$ the function becomes

$$f (x,y,z)=729n^5$$
which goes to $+\infty $ as $n\to+\infty $.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

for $y=z=kx$ we have:
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{x+y+z}{x^2y^2z^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {2k+1}{kx^5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify, you get
$$
\frac{1}{xy^2z^2} + \frac{1}{x^2yz^2} + \frac{1}{x^2y^2z}
$$
and is now clear the limit does not exist, since it could be infinite in both positive and negative directions...